# Does Polymer work in PHP files?

Tags: php, html, polymer

If I wanted to use Polymer in a PHP project - could I just use the elements in my PHP file, or should I simply be using post core-ajax and posts to handle the backend and leave files as HTML?

I haven't found a lot of documentation about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Derp. Good point. I'll give it a go. Just thought I could get someone's past experience in dealing with it before I dropped a bunch of polymer into my PHP project.

Comment: You can output html in PHP so why wouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure. Because it depends on html imports etc.

Comment: HTML imports is a client-side dependency, it will work if your browser knows how to do imports (Chrome) or if you have a polyfill (other browsers). It works on almost every server-side tehcnology, I've tested it with Java, PHP and Python servers, and with plain HTTP servers (Apache HTTPd, Nginx...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it can work. but if using php you could just feed back json to a polymer app in html by using json_encode on your php array of other output. the way polymer loads all the data on the initial load it would make app loading longer cause php would have to pre process everything before the page could render (this was my experience. and might not be the issue for someone that is not looking for single page app). IMO if using php for a backend it would be better to have php feed back json to a polymer app and just connect with core-ajax or any other ajax call.

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to do. I started just using materializecss but decided to go full-on polymer instead of just front-end framework.

Comment: using this method it would also open up the possibility to later convert the app to a chrome packaged app or apache cordova.

Answer (score -1):

I just dropped the components from the [Polymer tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/) into a test CakePHP project, and it works great.

Comment: what do you mean by "dropped"?